# Vector names not showing in R viewer, but they do when calling head()

Tags: r, vector

I got a couple named vectors.

One of them, `geneList`, is downloaded directly from a package: `data(geneList, package = "genekitr")`. It shows the names of the values both when calling `head()` and `view()`.
[head(geneList)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW48X.png)
[view(geneList)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz3f6.png)

However, the other named vector, `genlistdef` (generated by using `tibble::deframe` on a two column dataframe), only shows the names of the values when calling `head()`, but not in `view()`.
[head(genlistdef)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3HPX.png)
[view(genelistdef)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQrkP.png)

Anyone knows how can I make `genlistdef` behave like `geneList`?

I'm using R4.3.0 and RStudio Versión 2023.03.1+446.

I tried:

```
genlistdef <- genelistGSEA$x
names(genlistdef) <- genelistGSEA$name
```

and

```
x <- genelistGSEA$x
names <- genelistGSEA$name
genelistdef <- setNames(x, names)
```

but it all gives me the same result as `tibble::deframe`

Comment: Your view view is showing row names. Tilbbles don't maintain row names. See https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html. If you want to preserve that data move it from a row name into a column.